# FontAwesome 4.0.3 icons just giving boxes (or blank in IE9)

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a site I'm updating with new content. It was preloaded with FA 3.2.something. I'm trying to load in 4.0.3 and the icons are just giving me boxes (in IE9 they don't display anything).

I'm not even sure where to start. I replaced the old css and font files with the new ones, updated the classes called into my index.php file with the fa-iconname from icon-iconname.

Any ideas on what to troubleshoot?

---Found the answer---

Aside from changing all of the class calls from icon-[icon name] to fa-[icon name] you also have to call the fa class separately like

```
class="fa fa-[class name]"
```

Comment: Do the font files have the same name as before?  Are they definitely being called?

Comment: yeah, just figured it out too. The 4.0.3 specifications require two class calls instead of one. You have to call class="fa fa-[icon name]
 whereas before you could just call class="icon-[icon name]"

Also, the old "icon" class leader is now "fa". Not sure if I made that clear before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, just figured it out too.

The 4.0.3 specifications require two class calls instead of one. You have to call `class="fa fa-[icon name]` whereas before you could just call `class="icon-[icon name]"` Also, the old `"icon"` class leader is now `"fa"`.

Not sure if I made that clear before